# Unable to show extracted data from the table in fiddler

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api2

I have written the following code to extract all records from the table in the SQL server. There is no error in the code but when I run it in fiddler, I am getting null objects.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Student> Get()
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();

        myConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=PALLAVI-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=StudentDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select * from Tbl_Students;";
        sqlCmd.Connection = myConnection;

        myConnection.Open();

        reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        int rowCount = 0;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            rowCount++;
        }

        Student[] student = new Student[rowCount];
        for(int i=0;i<rowCount;i++)
        {
            student[i] = new Student();
        }

        int j = 0;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
          //  student[j] = new Student();
            student[j].Roll_Number = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0));
            student[j].FirstName = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
            student[j].LastName = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
            student[j].Class = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(3));
            student[j].Gender = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();

            j++;

        }

        return student.ToList();
        myConnection.Close();
    }
```

I have 5 records in the table. I am able to get 5 json objects but without the content.

Attaching the image from Fiddler:

[image]

Student.cs

```
namespace WebAPIDemo.Models
{
   public class Student
   {
      public int Roll_Number { get; set; }
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }
      public int Class { get; set; }
      public string Gender { get; set; }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your Student class?

Comment: I'm curious, if you put a debug statement on your return statement and inspect the list of student objects, do the values show null there?

Comment: Also, (slightly off topic) you need to move your connection close statement above the return statement, otherwise it's unreachable and your connection won't close.

Comment: @joshmcode, yes. I am unable to transfer the contents from the reader to the array.

Comment: @PallaviPrasad Don't read the value from reader two times. use only one while (reader.Read()) and place all your code inside it.

Comment: @Chandru, The first while loop is to get the number of records in the reader. Is there any other way to get the record count?

Comment: @PallaviPrasad I have posted the code check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, without taking count of records. I'm not using the array, I have created new instance of student for each record.

```
 public static List<Student> GetData()
    {
        List<Student> lstStudent = new List<Student>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PALLAVI-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=StudentDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Tbl_Students;", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();                   

                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    Student student =new Student();

                    student.Roll_Number = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0));
                    student.FirstName = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    student.LastName = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                    student.Class = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(3));
                    student.Gender = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();

                    lstStudent.Add(student);
                }                   

            }
        }
        return lstStudent;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

your first `while(reader.Read())` is the actual reader object with data. `DataReader` allows forward only read only access to a data row.The next `while` loop won't even execute because the `Read()` is already completed.So you're getting an array of 5 `Student` objects that are initialized with default values.

Instead of initializing an array of `Student` populate instances and add to a `List<Student>` inside the `while` loop.